# UPPAAL: bad CPU type in executable

Tags: terminal, apple-silicon, rosetta

I am using the terminal on an Apple M1 MacBook. I am executing the terminal with Rosetta, trying to be compatible for a tool that is not for ARM. The tool itself is [the UPPAAL tool for 32-bit Mac OS X, version 4.0.13](https://uppaal.org/downloads/). The program opens but I get an error when trying to use it:

```
Cannot run program "/Users/Me/Uppaal/bin-Darvin/server": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
```

I am getting this error if I try to use the script and if I try to run manually the executables, even if I am trying to execute them with "arch -x86_64" before them. I acknowledge that the problem is probably caused because my computer is ARM-based while this is probably not an ARM code. However, would it be possible to sort this out with Rosetta or any similar tool? Perhaps Rosetta is not working properly on my computer?

Comment: "Bad CPU type in executable" afaik is equally likely to be because it's 32-bit. There are 64-bit builds on there.

Comment: Looking at the downloads you need a 4.1 version for 64 bit Intel even though it is a development release.

Comment: @mmmmmm perfect! That worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Silicon macs can only run 64 bit code; 64 bit Intel is run via Rosetta.

As you say in the question you are trying to run a 32 bit version of UPPAAL. The mac can't run this and gives the error as expected of Bad CPU type in executable. Intel 32 bit and 64 bit are different CPUs as far as MacOS is concerned.

Looking at UPAALL's web site you need to run a development version of 4.1 or higher which is a 64 bit executable